# Windows azure push notication and catch the notification to a particular website page

Tags: php, ios, windows, azure, push-notification

Hi im working on a project who has an existing iOS app that uses windows cloud platform. Our task is to create a website for the app. One of the requirements is to enable to catch notifications created by the mobile app. For example if there is a new user, push notifications will be triggered and a website link will catch the notifications and save the data to a database. My question is, is it possible to catch a notification from windows azure push notification using a php script event listener?

I don't have any background on windows azure and i don't have any access to there windows azure account. The only thing they said is to give them the link of the script that will catch the notifications.

What are some steps thats need to be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible. Notification Hubs sets up communications so that you can send a notification out to a many different platforms at one time (Apple, Android, Windows Phone, Windows 8, etc.).  Each device registers with the Notification Hub (or the registration is done for them by a back end) and provides a unique device ID, also known as a Channel URI.  When you need to send a notification the Notification Hub then disperses that notification out to each of the correct Platform Notification Systems (PSNs) which then deliver the notification directly to the device.

I say all of that to indicate while it **might** be possible to register a listener that is not a device with the notification hub using a REST based API (You'd have to create a viable channel URI) I'm not sure there is any way to be listening as a php script to a PSN.  Also, the registrations do expire from time to time and so you'd need to make sure to keep registering.  Finally, no notification system is 100% guaranteed to deliver a notification.  The device could be off, it could be in a bad reception area, bad network connection, or the PSN just doesn't delivery it for some reason, etc.

My suggestion is to take a step back and modify the code where the notification is being produced and send it both to Notification Hubs for device distribution, but also send the content of that notification to your database directly, or have them right the message to a queue which is processed in the backend to save to the database if the database isn't local to the code generating the notifications.  This removes the notification hub involvement as far as your website is concerned.

If you really MUST look into the php script getting the messages then you can start by trying to figure out how php can receive messages from the PSNs, which is not an Azure issue.  You can use the [Notification Hubs REST APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn223264.aspx) to register for them, but I'm very skeptical of that route.

Comment: MikeWo - thank you for your answer. I was thinking it is possible like the recurly api push notification where it triggers when someone pays the subscription. Anyway, I will try your suggestion. Thanks again.